# Не могу получать и передавать данные между компонентами в vue + quasar

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar.js

На нас повесили выкинуть в отдельный компонент код, который по несколько раз повторяется. Взял кнопку "Очистить все". В итоге, при вызове компонента с кнопкой в компонент с формой, кнопка появляется, но вот при нажатии ничего не происходит.

Также в этот компонент до этого я выносил общую форму и присваивал к переменной, чтобы введенные данные при переходе в другое поле оставались, но видимо данные не передавались между компонентами и как только я начинал писать в другой, в первой все удалялось.

```
<template>
  <div class="row q-pt-xs q-gutter-x-sm">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <q-input
        v-model="filterOptions.nameGroup"
        label="Наименование группы"
        outlined
      />
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 flex items-center">
      <div class="row q-gutter-x-sm">
        <q-btn>
          Обновить
        </q-btn>
        <DeleteButtonVue />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import DeleteButtonVue from '../buttons/DeleteButton.vue';
import filterOptions from '@/components/buttons/DeleteButton.vue';
</script>
```

```
<template>
  <div class="groupsAndRoles">
    <q-btn
      rounded
      text-color="white"
      color="blue-grey-8"
      type="resert"
      @click="clearFilterOptions"
    >
      Очистить всё
    </q-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { MainFilterOptions } from '@/types/mainFilterOptions';

const defaultFilterOptions: MainFilterOptions = {
  dateFrom: '',
  dateUntil: '',
  isBlocked: false,
  login: '',
  fio: '',
  ip: '',
  mail: '',
  idOrg: 0,
  idDept: 0,
  asoz: '',
  nameGroup: '',
  nameRoles: '',
  projects: 0,
  subsystems: 0,
};

const filterOptions = ref<MainFilterOptions>({
  ...defaultFilterOptions,
});

function clearFilterOptions() {
  filterOptions.value = defaultFilterOptions;
}
</script>
```